# How to create custom Magento 2 Fotorama?

Tags: magento2, fotorama

How to fix fotorama magnifier on mouseleave?

**magnify-lens** not adding **magnify-hidden** class if mouseleave to right side or left side. magnify-hidden will be added if mouseleave to top or bottom.

How can I fix this? Should I create jquery for adding the magnify-hidden class? 
or can I customize on view.xml?

2nd questions. How can I fix fotorama thumb border to correct positions?

[image]